# Parse and SDWebImage Pods have HUGE problems after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I had an app in which I used CocoaPods to install Parse and SDWebImage. Everything worked just fine. Then I updated Xcode and it now fails with MULTIPLE issues. I was getting undefined object error messages, so I ran pod update. This got rid of those messages, but now it fails because:

```
Unknown type name 'PFFileObject'; did you mean 'PFObject'?
'SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h' file not found
```

I have confirmed that the file is there, I have tried doing just an import of UIImageView+WebCache.h on that class, I have cleaned the project, I have ran pod update, but nothing seems to help. How did one Xcode update manage to take an app that ran fine and without any code changes, prevent it from opening at all?

I've tried everything I can think of, even dragging in SDWebImage into my project, but that wouldn't work either. I've confirmed that both PFFileObject.h and UIImageView+WebCache.h both exist, the app just doesn't see it.

It seems that it thinks it is missing stuff, but they're actually there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which versions of Xcode, CocoaPods and the two pods in question are you using?

Comment: Xcode 15.1. Parse 1.19.4, Bolts 1.9.1

Comment: Can you please share the pod file?
So that we can have a look and check for the possible solution?

Comment: Also, Have you tried by the Package Manager of the SDWebImage?
Please try by performing the following steps:

Remove the related pods from the podfile
Xcode-> Click File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Dependency, enter "https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage.git" URL. 

Or you can login Xcode with your GitHub account and just type SDWebImage to search.
As per the recommendation of the repository, you could choose the "5.1.0" version while installing it.